# Prove the Leibniz's integral rule in a rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification, leibniz-integral-rule

What shown below is a reference form the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres.

> **Theorem**
>
> Let be $Q$ be a rectangle in $\Bbb R^n$; let $f:Q\times[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Denote $f$ by $f(x,t)$ for $x\in Q$ and $t\in[a,b]$. Then the function
> $$
> F(x):=\int_a^bf(x,t)dt
> $$
> is continuous on $Q$. Furthermore if $\partial f/\partial x_j$ is continuous on $Q\times[a,b]$ then
> $$
> \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}=\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x,t)dt
> $$
>
> This formula is called *Leibniz's integral rule*.
>
> *Proof*. We show that $F$ is continuous. The rectangle $Q\times[a,b]$ is compact; therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous on $Q\times[a,b]$. That is, given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
> $$
> |f(x_1,t_1)-f(x_0,t_0)|<\epsilon\,\,\,\text{whenever}\,\,\,|(x_1,t_1)-(x_0,t_0)|<\delta
> $$
> and thus
> $$
> |F(x_1)-F(x_0)|\le\int_a^b|f(x_1,t)-f(x_0,t)|\le\epsilon(b-a)
> $$
> when $|x_1-x_0|<\delta$.
>
> Now we prove the formula. So in calculating the integral and derivatives involved in Leibniz's rule, only the variables $x_j$ and $t$ are involved; all others are held constant. there fore it suffices to prove the theorem in the case where $n=1$ and $Q$ is an interval $[c,d]$ in $\Bbb R$. Let us set, for $x\in [c,d]$,
> $$
> G(x):=\int_a^bD_1f(x,t)dt
> $$
> We wish to show that $F'(x)$ exists and equals $G(x)$. For this purpose we apply (of all thins) the Fubini theorem. WE are given that $D_1 f$ is continuous on $[c,d]\times[a,b]$. Then
> $$
> \int_c^{x_0}G(x)=\int_c^{x_0}\int_a^bD_1f(x,t)=\int_a^b\int_c^{x_0}D_1f(x,t)=\int_a^b[f(x_0,t)-f(c,t)]=F(x_0)-F(c)
> $$
> Then for $x\in[c,d]$ we have
> $$
> \int_c^{x}G(\xi)=F(x)-F(c)$
> $$
> Since $G$ is continuous by step 1 we may apply the fundamental theorem of calculus once more to conclude that
> $$
> G(x)=F'(x)
> $$

So I did not understand why it suffices to prove the theorem for the case $n=1$ and thus I ask to explain it more **formally** or to prove the theorem with not this restriction. In particular I try to make the following two attempt of proof.

**MY PROOF ATTEMPT**

So we observe that
$$
\frac{F(x+h\hat e_i)-F(x)}h=\int_a^b\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i,t)-f(x,t)}hdt
$$
for each $x\in Q$ so that the statement would follows showing that
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_a^b\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i,t)-f(x,t)}h=\\
\int_a^b\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i,t)-f(x,t)}h
$$
but unfortunately I do not able to do it. Anyway if $D_if(x,t)$ is continuous on $Q\times[a,b]$ then through the same argument of set $1$ for any $\epsilon>0$ there must exist $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|D_if(y,t)-D_i(x,t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}
$$
whether $|y-x|<\delta$ so that for any $x\in Q$ let be $C(x,\delta)$ a cubic neighborhood of radius of such $\delta$ centered at $x$. Now by the mean value theorem if $x\in\text{int}\,Q$ there must exist $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i)-f(x,t)}h=Df(x+\lambda h\hat e_i)\cdot\hat e_i=D_if(x+\lambda h\hat e_i)
$$
and thus
$$
\Biggl|\frac{F(x+h\hat e_i)-F(x)}h-\int_a^bD_if(x,t)\Biggl|=\\\Biggl|\int_a^bD_if(x+\lambda h\hat e_i,t)-D_if(x,t)\Biggl|\le\int_a^b|D_if(x+\lambda h\hat e_i,t)-D_if(x,t)|\le\int_a^b\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}=\epsilon
$$
so that the formula holds when $x\in\text{int}\, Q$ but what's happen if $x\in\text{bd}\,Q$? Indeed in this case the positive or negative limt
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{\pm}}\int_a^b\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i,t)-f(x,t)}h
$$
exists so that I ask if the equality
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_a^b\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i,t)-f(x,t)}h=\\
\int_a^b\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h\hat e_i,t)-f(x,t)}h
$$
effectively holds. I point out that **I did not study Lebesgue integration and measure theory** so that I ask courteously to not use them.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: This is fine more or less as is.  It seems you are worried about the case where $x \in \partial Q$.  Nothing is different except the derivative $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} $ is the limit of $\frac{f(x+h \hat{e_i},t)-f(x,t)}{h}$ as $h \to 0$ with $x+h\hat{e_i} \in Q$. That might be a one-sided limit depending on which part of the boundary $x$ is located.  In the end it does not matter since the mean value theorem applies in the same way: $f(x + h \hat{e_i},t) - f(x,t) = D_if(x + \lambda h \hat{e_i},t)$ since that intermediate point is inside the $Q$ by convexity.

Comment: Also the estimate of $|D_i f(x+\lambda h \hat{e_i},t) - D_if(x,t)|$ is made in the same way by uniform continuity as both $x,x+\lambda h \hat{e_i} \in Q$.

Comment: @RRL So you are substantially claiming that if $f$ is a scalar function defined in a closed rectangle $Q$ of $\Bbb R^n$ then the mean-value theorem can be applied for the boundary points too?

Comment: Yes -- consider $Q = [a_1,b_1]\times [a_2,b_2]$ and $x = (x_1,a_2) \in \partial Q$.  With $h$ sufficiently small $x + h \hat{e_1} = (x_1+h,a_1) \in Q$ and $D_1f(\cdot,a_2)$ exists at all points on the segment between $x$ and $x + h \hat{e_1}$ so the MVT applies.